# How do i create a transition that does the opposite of "Cover vertical"

Tags: ios, xcode, view, transition

I am using the storyboard in Xcode to create a prototype of my app. At one point i have a view that slides up using the segue "cover vertical". How can have that view slide back down again if users press cancel on that screen.

Basically I am looking for a transition that makes me take the user back to the previous screen. To the below layer that was just covered by the view that slid up from the bottom if you will.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

When you are in the view controller, simply call

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

If the view controller transition is cover vertical, it will simply reverse the animation and go back down while uncovering your previous view controller.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? How exactly do i do this?

Comment: So, the return transition back to the previous view will not be defined in the storyboard. It can only be done in the code, usually in the view controller itself. This is the case for pretty much all return transitions. Does this help?